Nested ViewModel Not Being Populated When Form Is Submitted
I'm having a problem getting my nested view model to populate when the form is submitted.
This is the parent view model.
public class OverallViewModel
{
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }

    public CustomerDetailsViewModel CustomerDetails{ get; set; }

    public CustomerDetailsViewModel()
    {
        CustomerDetails= new CustomerDetailsViewModel();
    }
}

The nested view model:
public class CustomerDetailsViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Title { get; set; }

    public int SelectedTitle { get; set; }
}

The View:
@model ViewModels.Overview.OverviewViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToOverview", "Overview", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <div>
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OrderNumber)

      <div>
        @Html.Partial("_CustomerDetails", Model.CustomerDetailsViewModel)
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add To Summary" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}

The partial view:
@model ViewModels.Overview.CustomerDetailsViewModel

<h3>Customer Details</h3>

<div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Title)
        <div class="controls">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedTitle,
                new SelectList(Model.Title, "Value", "Text"),
                "-- Please Select --",
                new { id = "title-dropdown" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

When I click the 'Add To Summary' button, the value selected in the Title drop down list is not populated in the CustomerDetailsViewModel, OrderNumber is populated though.  I can't figure out why this isn't working, as far as I can tell I have it set up correctly.  Am I missing something?

Look at the data that you're supplying to the DropDownList:
    new SelectList(Model.Title, "Value", "Text")

And your model:
    public class CustomerDetailsViewModel
    {
       public List<SelectListItem> Title { get; set; } // where is the list of options?
       public int SelectedTitle { get; set; } // why int?
    }

This isn't going to work. Instead you need to give the DropDownList a proper data source to work with:
    public class CustomerDetailsViewModel
    {
       public List<SelectListItem> Titles { get; set; } // populate a list of options here: = new List<SelectListItem>()...
       public string SelectedTitle { get; set; } // this is now a string (assuming the title is a string)
    }

Then in your view, do this:
    <div class="controls">
          @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedTitle,
              model.Titles,
              "-- Please Select --",
              new { id = "title-dropdown" })
    </div>

I don't know the context of what you're trying to do here...but hopefully this will put you in the right direction.
